# htaccess rewrite a file to another rewritten URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect abc.php to another URL that's also a rewrite, it does seem to be picked up, but redirects to abc.php in another folder, which means that it hits the main application logic, which it should not since the rewrite URL skips the main application.

```
RewriteRule ^abc.php$ some/other/rewritten/url/we/want/to/redirect/to [NC]
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Can you clarify what your other rules look like?

Comment: What do you want to do more than this? If it's modified without redirect, you'll be sure that, with your rewriterule, abc.php will be rewritten internally, and it will be treated like if it were `some/other/rewritten/url/we/want/to/redirect/to`. I don't know what you want **more** than this ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question. There was an issue with some sub-directories having their own .htaccess that I've managed to overlook. The rule was otherwise working ok.